# IIS won't let you download EXE files, reports 404

Tags: iis, http-status-code-404, windows

In my quest to get WSUS updates working I've gotten stuck at this stage. WSUS reports that it cannot download the updates and upon trying via Internet Explorer it reports a 404 error.

A txt file in the same directory appears fine. Here is the output from the log for one of the update exe files:

```
#Fields: date time s-sitename s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status 
2010-08-23 00:57:41 W3SVC1789576717 10.30.0.69 GET /Content/0E/DD7AE25A341E69544BA934B532CD270751C62A0E.exe - 8530 DOMAIN\username 10.30.0.20 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+5.2;+Trident/4.0;+.NET+CLR+1.1.4322;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.0.04506.30;+.NET+CLR+3.0.04506.648;+.NET+CLR+3.5.21022;+.NET+CLR+3.0.4506.2152;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729) 404 2 1260
```

From this I gather that the error "404 2 1260" relates to:

> 404.2-Lockdown Policy Prevents This Request

Things I have tried:

- Checking that the MIME type is defined (it is)
- Checking the permissions on the folder so that it's said to read and not execute (it is)
- Allowing it via Web Service Extensions (i'm not sure how to do this, read this suggestion for things like perl/ASP scripts)

Does anyone have any other suggestions for what I could try? I'm quite new to Windows Server Administration, been using Linux for past 3 years or so and finding it much tougher!

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long day of checking, finally realised that they were talking about a different permissions box! In the websites properties removed execute permissions and all is fine now.